# fixed sidebar with dynamic content in vue js

Tags: vue.js, vue-component, vue-router

i'm trying to make my content component dynamic.(using vue-router)

this is my code:

```vue
<template>
    <div class="row mb-3" id="customer-panel">
        <Breadcrumb></Breadcrumb>
        <CustomerSidebar></CustomerSidebar>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <PersonalInfo></PersonalInfo>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

any thing is fixed in all pages except **PersonalInfo** component.

and this is my route:

```vue
{
        path: '/customer',
        component: Profile,
        redirect: '/customer/profile',
        children: [
            {
                path: 'profile',
                name: 'profile',
                component: Profile
            },
            {
                path: 'order',
                name: 'order',
                component: Order
            },
        ]
    }
```

what should i do?

i don't want to repeat my code and copy & past in another component.
i just want when i go to order route, Order component loaded instead of **PersonalInfo**.

what is the best way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/nested-routes.html

You can acheive your desired result with `<router-view></router-view>`

Any nested routes / children of your parent route will be rendered here, on route change.

Component:

```
<template>
    <div class="row mb-3" id="customer-panel">
        <Breadcrumb></Breadcrumb>
        <CustomerSidebar></CustomerSidebar>
        <div class="col-lg-9">

            <router-view></router-view>

        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

Routes:

```
{
        path: '/customer',
        component: Customer,
        children: [
            {
                path: 'profile',
                name: 'profile',
                component: Profile
            },
            {
                path: 'order',
                name: 'order',
                component: Order
            },
        ]
}
```

Comment: i'm using <router-view></router-view> in App.vue (main component). should i use it again?

Comment: Yes, you can use it within a parent component to render nested / children

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you could try using dynamic component selection using the `is` attribute:

```
<template>
    <div class="row mb-3" id="customer-panel">
        <Breadcrumb></Breadcrumb>
        <CustomerSidebar></CustomerSidebar>
        <div class="col-lg-9">
            <component is="currentComponent"></component>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

And associate `currentComponent` variable to the name of the component you want to use in the current route.

```
{
    path: '/customer',
    component: Profile,
    redirect: '/customer/profile',
    children: [
        {
            path: 'profile',
            name: 'profile',
            components: { default: Profile, currentComponent: MyComponent1 }
        },
        {
            path: 'order',
            name: 'order',
            component: {default: Order, currentComponent: MyComponent2 } 
        },
    ]
}
```

See:

- https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components
- https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/passing-props.html

Comment: this is not a direct vue-router implementation as asked